# ignoring commas as thousands separators in csv files

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse

I have some datasets that have multiple rows  like in the data.frae `df` below.

Ultimately, I really need the integers at the very end of the string, after the comma that is outside the double-quotes. But the comma as the thousands separator seems to really complicate things.

It would be useful to save the row labels for each count (i.e. $5,000 - $9,999), but I could do without that.

the code below returns the row label and the count in the same column.

Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
text<-'"Text / some other text / some other text / $5,000-$9,999", 10,000.00'
df<-data.frame(text=text)
df %>% 
  separate(., text, into=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), sep='/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a second `separate`, like this?

```
df %>% 
  separate(., text, into=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), sep='/') %>%
  separate(d, into = c("d", "e"), sep = "\", ")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish your task by using R Base's regular expression capabilities.

```
library(tidyr)
text<-'"Text / some other text / some other text / $5,000-$9,999", 10,000.00'
df<-data.frame(text=text)
df %>% mutate(my_number = unlist(regmatches(text, gregexpr( ' [0-9](.*)$' ,text)))) %>%  
       mutate(my_number = as.integer(sub(',','', my_number))) %>%  
  head 


text   my_number
1 "Text / some other text / some other text / $5,000-$9,999", 10,000.00     
10000
```